# How to make an Azure Service Bus Node.js client connect via HTTPS (port 443), not port 5671?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

We are using the `@azure/service-bus` package to listen for Azure Service Bus messages in a Node.js application. Unfortunately the default port 5671 is blocked in our environment.

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420904/how-azure-service-bus-queue-delivers-messages-to-client-on-https-mode) the connectivity mode can be changed to HTTPS (port 443), at least from .NET (and maybe Java) like so:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https;
```

How can we achieve the same in a Node.js based application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `https` support, you will need to use `WebSockets`. Try to create your Service Bus client using the code below:

```
const connectionString = 'your service bus connection string';
const connectionOptions = {
    webSocketOptions: {
        webSocket : WebSocket
    }
};
const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, connectionOptions);
```

Now you'll be connecting to your Service Bus using `https` over port 443 instead of `AMQP` using port 5671.

For more details, please see [`ServiceBusClientOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest) and [`ServiceBusClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclient?view=azure-node-latest).

Comment: That's it, thank you very much! Had to `npm install ws` first and add `const WebSocket = require('ws');` to make in run in Node.js but then it was working!